# Verify when $f(x) = a^x, \frac{dy}{dx}$

Tags: calculus

> To differentiate $f(x)$ in the form of $ax^b$, $\frac{dy}{dx} = bax^{b-1}$.

I need to differentiate something in the form of $c^x$. $c$ is a constant, and $x$ is the variable. Bearing this in mind, I have assumed that:

> $a = 1, b = x, x = c$, where the term on the left of each equation is in relation to the top statement, and the right being the equation which I need to differentiate.

So am I correct that $\frac{dy}{dx} = xc^{x-1}$?

For example, differentiating $2^x$ = $x(2^{x-1})$?

Comment: Nope, the power rule you cited is only true for $a$ and $b$ constants. You need to use logarithmic differentiation, or look at $\frac{d}{dx} \exp(\ln f(x))$

Comment: Read http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/403884/why-isnt-the-derivative-of-ex-equal-to-xex-1 to see what does not work in your guess.

Comment: @mic, thnx, but I don't understand half of it lol.

Comment: power rule works on constant exponents

Comment: Here's a similar question I answered using base conversion. I explain everything here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2218294/implicit-differentiation-quesrion/2218847#2218847

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have 
$$(2^x)' = (\exp(x\log(2)))' = \exp(x\log(2)) \log(2) = 2^x\log(2)$$ This also gives you a way to compute $a^x$ for some $a>0$ by simply writing $$a^x = \exp(x \log(a))$$ So to summarize, your assumption is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

$\frac {d(a^x)}{dx}=a^x\log a$.

$\frac {d(x^a)}{dx}=ax^{a-1}$.

They are different. To prove the differentiation of an expression, instead of your method, you should use the definition of differentiation at a point:

$\frac {df(x_0)}{dx} = \lim_{x\to x_0}\frac {f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$.

In most cases, you need to calculate some frequently occurred limits.